# Same Spring Project Running successfully on tomcat but not on Jetty

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, maven-jetty-plugin

This is the git hub link for my project.

https://github.com/asmanjas1/WebApp

The problem here is ....when i am deploying my war in tomcat, i am able to get the response from servlet. 
But when i am deploying through jetty maven plugin, the warning message is showing in the terminal as:: WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringRestHibernateExample/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring', and not getting the response and 404 error is coming in the UI.

I don't know where i did mistake.
can you please look into my web.xml, spring-servlet.xml and any other related file you think and let me know where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you need to add tomcat excluison in spring-boot-starter-web dependency such as

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

example : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-jetty/pom.xml